# Where to place POCOs validation - N-layers arquitecture

Tags: .net, design-patterns, repository-pattern, layer, poco

I am developing an n-layer app.
One of the layer is the **BusinessLayer** and consumes a set of POCOs defined in the **CoreLayer**

**CoreLayer**

- POCOs (classes with properties)
- Repository interfaces (use the POCOs as parameters types) For example :

  ```
  public interfaces ICarRepository
  {
   IEnumerable<CarPOCO> GetAllCars();
  }

  public class CarPOCO
  {
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
  }
  ```

**DataAccessLayer**

- Custom implementation of IRepositories. For example with SQLServer data access.

**BusinessLayer**:

- Businnes logic
- I want to put here the validation of the POCOs data, but I am not sure if is the right place, or how to deal with it

What do you think? How will you do that?

Many thanks, you are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the businesslayer looks like the best option. Maybe you can use something like `FluentValidation` to separate your validation logic cleanly.

More info at: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation